# Is it possible to distinguish rest and movement in hyperbolic universe?

Tags: physics, hyperbolic-geometry, philosophy

Imagine a large body (for example, a planet) in 3D hyperbolic space. Now imagine the planet starts moving in a straight line at constant speed.

In Euclidean space, all points would move along parallel lines. In hyperbolic space, however, most points will be moving along equidistant curves, or hypercycles.

But points moving along a curve should experience some sort of force. If an observer is on the surface of the planet, he should be able to measure larger or smaller force depending on how close he is to the axis of movement.

This leads to conclusion that, unlike Euclidean space, hyperbolic space would allow an observer to determine whether the planet is in rest or whether it is moving without referring to any other body -- absolute rest/movement, in effect.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: I'm not precisely sure of the answer, but it strikes me a suspicious to think of geodesics as "curved" - they are more or less the universe's notion of straight. Especially consider this: The acceleration along a great circle is *normal* to the surface of a sphere. If you were a flat thing living on the surface of a sphere, you wouldn't even know that there was such a thing as "normal to the surface of a sphere" and I doubt you'd perceive any force. (Especially once we know that a sphere may be thought of *without reference to an embedding*)

Comment: *But points moving along a curve should experience some sort of force* That doesn't sound like a consistent idea of "hyperbolic universe." Wouldn't objects experiencing no forces in a hyperbolic universe follow hyperbolic lines? It sounds like you're thinking of objects in a hyperbolic universe obeying physics according to Euclidean lines. Milo's comment just now is getting at the same thing, I think

Comment: Not really, I think. I don't consider geodesics curved; but not all points of the planet can move along a geodesic -- only points on one special line. If they all moved along straight lines, the planet wouldn't hold together, as the lines would be ultraparallel and diverge. So, if the planet is solid, then some of its points must move along curved paths.

Comment: I believe that this is pretty much exactly what is going on in deep gravity wells, such as inside the event horizon of a black hole: the negative curvature in such environments has the effect of "tidal forces" which pull matter apart.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to my initial gut feeling, this sounds highly plausible. If you assume that any body which is *not* moving (with constant speed) along a geodesic experiences some force, then you can simply take four test bodies, forming a regular hyperbolic tetrahedron, and consider translating that through space. As you said, a hyperbolic translation only moves points on a specific geodesic along that same geodesic, while all other points are moved along curves equidistant to that geodesic. So at most two corners of the tetrahedron can remain without force, at least two others will take a curved trajectory and hence be subject to some force. So I'd say you are right.

Whether the force is sufficiently large to be measured in practice depends of course on the scale of things, so we still don't know whether the universe is flat or not.

Comment: lets discuss, i added a contrary answer, please add your counter-counter arguments :)

Comment: I came with a bit simpler example that only requires two dimensions: A long bar that moves perpendicularly to its direction. If it was just a collection of points, the distance between points would grow with time as they move along ultraparallel lines. But since it's a solid bar, it will resist and strain. Now, cut the bar in the middle. If it wasn't moving before, both halves should stay together. If it was moving, they should move apart, as each of them will now follow its own straight line.

Comment: And as I was writing that, I might realize the missing piece of my thoughts. I was asking about the geometry of space, but what about spacetime? After all, if the spacetime is also hyperbolic, then a group of bodies would grow apart even when not moving as their worldlines would be divergent (effect akin to expansion of space). In such situation, a bar would experience strain whether it was moving or not. However, in the original example with planet, standing still would mean the same force would affect all points on the planet, while movement would affect points closer to the axis less...

Comment: Also note that if the space is hyperbolic, but time is not, then the spacetime as a whole is not isotropic -- and so the spacetime directions of "rest" and "movement" are not equivalent and it's no wonder they can be distinguished!

Comment: @Marek14 Considering spacetime as a whole is indeed a new twist to this, which I hadn't considered. So all inert objects are moving through spacetime in the same way, and it depends on the observer whether that movement appears to be more space-like or more time-like? And everything drifts apart, while the drifting apart due to motion and the one due to the passage of time exactly compensate for the amount time dilation? Sounds plausible. Since spacetime is modeled as $\mathbb R^{3,1}$, and hyperbolic space as $\mathbb P(\mathbb R^{3,1})$, I wonder about the signature for hyperbolic spacetime.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add much more to this -- I tend to get lost in these areas of mathematics. So I am not sure how exactly would hyperbolic spacetime look and how would the drifting compare with expansion of our own universe.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a discussion and hoping for insights:

NO it is not possible to distinguish rest and movement in hyperbolic universe ( I follow my gut feeling)

(sorry this is a bit rambling but i found the question intruiging)

I would suggest the following two counter examples:

Counter example 1: "moving earth"

The earth is moving at quite a high speed (around the sun) but standing on the earth can i measure intrinsicly (thus not calculate with known positions of the sun and earth) in which direction i am moving?

Counter example 2: "spherical triangle"

the idea behind the question seems to be that somehow you can measure some kind of distortion (because points on the surface don't move in straight lines) 
the same would apply to a moving triangle on a sphere (on a sphere the geodesics are also not equidistant), still triangles can move around on spheres without distortion. so also no measurement of distortions can be made.

General remarks:

it all seems to be going back to what in the old days (1890-1910) was called "the axiom of free (undistorted) movement". I think in short it was that for free movement the containing space must have a **constant** curvature. 
so figures / objects don't change form/angles while moving.

a hyperbolic universe has an **constant** negative curvature.

an example of a structure that does not have a constant curvature is a (normal) torus, triangles on a torus that have the same side lengths can have different angles, compare a triangle on the inside (negative curvature) with one on the outside (positive curvature) of a torus, for this reason 
triangles cannot be moved in every directions without distortion.

Discussion

I make this post a community wiki, let people who agree with my points add  their remarks here, and I hope MvG will do the same so people suportingbhim can add to his points.  (ps don't remove comments of others , but do improve them)

Comment: For “Moving earth”: Shoot a cannonball straight up in the sky. If you shoot away from the sun, then due to the preservation of angular momentum it will rotate around the sun slower than earth, and will come down “behind” its launch position. I'm not sure whether this effect is the same everywhere in the plane of ecliptic, but at least you can detect *that* you are moving and also the plane of the rotation.

Comment: Does your “spherical triangle” refer to a a triangle on a sphere in our (presumably Euclidean) universe, or in some abstract two-dimensional spherical space? In the former case, the comparison is flawed, since you could determine intrinsically that the triangle itself is bent, or not fully within the sphere. In the latter case, the argument still holds. But it's not so much about that the triangle must neccessarily get distorted, but more that resisting said distortion is possible, but requires some (theoretically measurable) force. Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Example 1: Yes, this should be possible to measure on Earth (at least in theory). If not, just increase the mass of Sun.

Comment: On 2: It's not that it is impossible to move a triangle on a sphere without distortion. Instead, it is impossible to move it without distortion in such a way that every point of the triangle would move along a geodesic with a constant speed. For example, if the triangle has two vertices on sphere's "equator" and you move it along that equator, then the third vertex would move along a "parallel", which is not a geodesic.

Comment: Example 2: What MvG said: first of all, the triangle you're moving would explicitly NOT be a mathematical (ideal) triangle, but a physical object with density, mass, etc. In that case, various parts of the triangle would express varying forces (they would feel "pushed" towards the axis of movement, the more the further they'd be away).

Comment: Finally, I actually agree with Willemien that it SHOULD be impossible to distinguish rest and movement according to principle of relativity. It's just that I came with this thought experiment that says otherwise, so either there's a flaw in the experiment, or principle of relativity only holds in Euclidean geometry, or there is something else which compensates the forces and makes principle of relativity still hold.